# background-size: contain not showing the whole picture

Tags: css, contain, background-size

I'm wondering why contain works like this.
This is my HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Zero to Mastery | Landing Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="landingPageStyle.css">    
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Now, this is my CSS code:

```
body {
/* min-height: 100%;   */
width: 600px;
height: 600px;
border: 4px solid red;
background-image: url('Nature500x400.jpg');
background-size: contain;   
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

My question is this: why is not the whole background picture inside the body? Why the picture exceed the border like in this picture of browser window:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDuzD.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the styles to `html` instead of `body` will fix this problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Zero to Mastery | Landing Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="landingPageStyle.css">    
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Use `html` instead:

```
html {
/* min-height: 100%;   */
width: 600px;
height: 600px;
border: 4px solid red;
background-image: url('Nature500x400.jpg');
background-size: contain;   
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to `background-size:cover`. You will need to add this property to a full-width div inside your body. You can not add it to the body

```
div {
/* min-height: 100%;   */
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
border: 4px solid red;
background-image: url('Nature500x400.jpg');
background-size: cover;   
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: add the background to a full-width div inside your body. answer updated

Answer (score 0):

background-size: contain  not work in body tag

Try this

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Zero to Mastery | Landing Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="landingPageStyle.css">    
</head>

<body>
<div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

and css

```
    div {
width: 600px;
height: 600px;
border: 4px solid red;
background-image: url('img Url');
background-size: contain;   
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: That is better. Just one more question. Why there is no space to the right side of the image? Image is 500 pixels wide and width of the div is 600 pixels.

Comment: because the property of background-size is contain

Comment: if you want the background image is displayed in its original size just change the background-size to auto

Comment: try background-size: 100% @Darko